# Cloudflare 504 Gateway error when trying to connect to the site

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy to my node app, I've tried a multitude of things to attempt to fix it like reinstalling it, using apache as a reverse proxy (that didn't work).

It was working before, this started to happen when I messed with the conf file to try to get letsencrypt certificates to be used because the site was showing unsecure, and when I try to connect to the site with the server IP itself there's not a response either.

This is my Nginx config

```
#The Nginx server instance
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name ppealliance.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        # location /overview {
        #     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000$request_uri;
        #     proxy_redirect off;
        # }
    }
}
```

The Errors being thrown out of Nginx

```
2022/06/08 15:45:57 [notice] 1036070#1036070: using inherited sockets from "6;7;"
2022/06/08 15:47:20 [emerg] 1036291#1036291: open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:60
2022/06/08 15:49:18 [error] 1036305#1036305: *1 upstream timed out (110: Unknown error) while reading response header from upstream, client: *Client's IP*, server: ppealliance.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "ppealliance.com"
```

And the nodejs app where things are supposed to be routed through

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const login = require("../modules/login")
const app = express(); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser())
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', '../public/views');
app.use( express.static( "public" ) );

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    login.redirect(req, res)
});


app.get('/admin-login', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('admin-login', { title:'Admin login'});
}); 

app.post('/admin-login-cookies', (req, res) => {
    login.cookiecheck(req, res)
});

app.get('/signup-1', (req, res) => {
    res.render('signup-1', { title:'Signup Part One'});
});


app.post('/admin-login', (req, res) => {
    login.login(req,res)
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    login.redirect(req, res)
});


app.listen(3000, 'localhost', () => {
    console.log('app is alive');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your app is running? You can check it with `netstat -nlpt`, look if there's an app on port 3000 to forward requests to.

Error 502 or 504 usually means that the app is down or not available.

Comment: yes it is running, is also logs in the console when it starts listening to port 3000